# Regularity of a function depending on first exit time of martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes

Consider a parametrised martingale as follows :

$$X^x_t := x+ \int_0^t\sqrt{2p_s} \, dW_s,$$

where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion and $(p_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a locally square integrable process satisfying $p_t\ge 1$ for all $t\ge 0$. Set $\tau^x:=\{t\ge 0: X^x_t\notin [0,1]\}$ and define the function $F: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by

$$F(x):=\mathbb E \left[\int_0^{\min(1,\tau_x)} \big(1+\log(p_s)\big) \, ds \right].$$

Can we show $F$ is continuous, Hölder-continuous or Lipschitz?

Comment: Before discussing F, one main question here is whether the law of $\tau_{x}$ is continuous/Holder/Lipschitz. As mentioned here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357316/question-about-the-exit-time-of-a-time-homogeneous-it%C3%B4-diffusion, a good start is to study the Fokker-Plank equation  for exit times.

Comment: generally there are continuous-dependence results as mentioned here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362570/differentiable-dependence-on-the-initial-condition-of-the-solution-of-a-sde/436132#436132, so you might be able to use those for F.